# Clustered standard error bars for two-way bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I am looking for help with code for adding clustered standard errors to a two-way bar chart generated using `ggplot`. All of the packages I find are for regression results.

I have data in which 1200 respondents each rated 10 profiles (n=12,000). I want to plot the means (Y) by X with standard errors for each category of X, but reflecting the clustered structure of the data. I know how to add regular standard error bars. Bonus if we can add 95% confidence intervals instead of just the clustered SEs, but I can do that step myself.

Edited to add an excerpt of the data & libraries used:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

data <- structure(list(
  id = c(1524155369, 1524155369, 1524155369, 
         1524155369, 1524155369, 1524155369, 1524155369, 1524155369, 1524155369, 
         1524155369, 1524155365, 1524155365, 1524155365, 1524155365, 1524155365, 
         1524155365, 1524155365, 1524155365, 1524155365, 1524155365, 1524154461, 
         1524154461, 1524154461, 1524154461, 1524154461, 1524154461, 1524154461, 
         1524154461, 1524154461, 1524154461, 1524154363, 1524154363, 1524154363, 
         1524154363, 1524154363, 1524154363, 1524154363, 1524154363, 1524154363, 
         1524154363, 1524154063, 1524154063, 1524154063, 1524154063, 1524154063, 
         1524154063, 1524154063, 1524154063, 1524154063, 1524154063, 1524153973, 
         1524153973, 1524153973, 1524153973, 1524153973, 1524153973, 1524153973, 
         1524153973, 1524153973, 1524153973, 1524152701, 1524152701, 1524152701, 
         1524152701, 1524152701, 1524152701, 1524152701, 1524152701, 1524152701, 
         1524152701, 1524150159, 1524150159, 1524150159, 1524150159, 1524150159, 
         1524150159, 1524150159, 1524150159, 1524150159, 1524150159, 1524150141, 
         1524150141, 1524150141, 1524150141, 1524150141, 1524150141, 1524150141, 
         1524150141, 1524150141, 1524150141, 1524150129, 1524150129, 1524150129, 
         1524150129, 1524150129, 1524150129, 1524150129, 1524150129, 1524150129, 
         1524150129, 1524150111, 1524150111, 1524150111, 1524150111, 1524150111, 
         1524150111, 1524150111, 1524150111, 1524150111, 1524150111, 1524150043, 
         1524150043, 1524150043, 1524150043, 1524150043, 1524150043, 1524150043, 
         1524150043, 1524150043, 1524150043, 1524150019, 1524150019, 1524150019, 
         1524150019, 1524150019, 1524150019, 1524150019, 1524150019, 1524150019, 
         1524150019, 1524150015, 1524150015, 1524150015, 1524150015, 1524150015, 
         1524150015, 1524150015, 1524150015, 1524150015, 1524150015, 1524149955, 
         1524149955, 1524149955, 1524149955, 1524149955, 1524149955, 1524149955, 
         1524149955, 1524149955, 1524149955, 1524149941, 1524149941, 1524149941, 
         1524149941, 1524149941, 1524149941, 1524149941, 1524149941, 1524149941, 
         1524149941, 1524149381, 1524149381, 1524149381, 1524149381, 1524149381, 
         1524149381, 1524149381, 1524149381, 1524149381, 1524149381, 1524149359, 
         1524149359, 1524149359, 1524149359, 1524149359, 1524149359, 1524149359, 
         1524149359, 1524149359, 1524149359, 1524149327, 1524149327, 1524149327, 
         1524149327, 1524149327, 1524149327, 1524149327, 1524149327, 1524149327, 
         1524149327, 1524149243, 1524149243, 1524149243, 1524149243, 1524149243, 
         1524149243, 1524149243, 1524149243, 1524149243, 1524149243, 1524149241, 
         1524149241, 1524149241, 1524149241, 1524149241, 1524149241, 1524149241, 
         1524149241, 1524149241, 1524149241, 1524149153, 1524149153, 1524149153, 
         1524149153, 1524149153, 1524149153, 1524149153, 1524149153, 1524149153, 
         1524149153, 1524149079, 1524149079, 1524149079, 1524149079, 1524149079, 
         1524149079, 1524149079, 1524149079, 1524149079, 1524149079, 1524149001, 
         1524149001, 1524149001, 1524149001, 1524149001, 1524149001, 1524149001, 
         1524149001, 1524149001, 1524149001, 1524148993, 1524148993, 1524148993, 
         1524148993, 1524148993, 1524148993, 1524148993, 1524148993, 1524148993, 
         1524148993, 1524148973, 1524148973, 1524148973, 1524148973, 1524148973, 
         1524148973, 1524148973, 1524148973, 1524148973, 1524148973, 1524148869, 
         1524148869, 1524148869, 1524148869, 1524148869, 1524148869, 1524148869, 
         1524148869, 1524148869, 1524148869, 1524148863, 1524148863, 1524148863, 
         1524148863, 1524148863, 1524148863, 1524148863, 1524148863, 1524148863, 
         1524148863, 1524148797, 1524148797, 1524148797, 1524148797, 1524148797, 
         1524148797, 1524148797, 1524148797, 1524148797, 1524148797, 1524148765, 
         1524148765, 1524148765, 1524148765, 1524148765, 1524148765, 1524148765, 
         1524148765, 1524148765, 1524148765, 1524148747, 1524148747, 1524148747, 
         1524148747, 1524148747, 1524148747, 1524148747, 1524148747, 1524148747, 
         1524148747, 1524148735, 1524148735, 1524148735, 1524148735, 1524148735, 
         1524148735, 1524148735, 1524148735, 1524148735, 1524148735, 1524148709, 
         1524148709, 1524148709, 1524148709, 1524148709, 1524148709, 1524148709, 
         1524148709, 1524148709, 1524148709, 1524148705, 1524148705, 1524148705, 
         1524148705, 1524148705, 1524148705, 1524148705, 1524148705, 1524148705, 
         1524148705, 1524148699, 1524148699, 1524148699, 1524148699, 1524148699, 
         1524148699, 1524148699, 1524148699, 1524148699, 1524148699, 1524148693, 
         1524148693, 1524148693, 1524148693, 1524148693, 1524148693, 1524148693, 
         1524148693, 1524148693, 1524148693, 1524148663, 1524148663, 1524148663, 
         1524148663, 1524148663, 1524148663, 1524148663, 1524148663, 1524148663, 
         1524148663, 1524148653, 1524148653, 1524148653, 1524148653, 1524148653, 
         1524148653, 1524148653, 1524148653, 1524148653, 1524148653, 1524148649, 
         1524148649, 1524148649, 1524148649, 1524148649, 1524148649, 1524148649, 
         1524148649, 1524148649, 1524148649, 1524148511, 1524148511, 1524148511, 
         1524148511, 1524148511, 1524148511, 1524148511, 1524148511, 1524148511, 
         1524148511, 1524148505, 1524148505, 1524148505, 1524148505, 1524148505, 
         1524148505, 1524148505, 1524148505, 1524148505, 1524148505, 1524148395, 
         1524148395, 1524148395, 1524148395, 1524148395, 1524148395, 1524148395, 
         1524148395, 1524148395, 1524148395, 1524148365, 1524148365, 1524148365, 
         1524148365, 1524148365, 1524148365, 1524148365, 1524148365, 1524148365, 
         1524148365, 1524146079, 1524146079, 1524146079, 1524146079, 1524146079, 
         1524146079, 1524146079, 1524146079, 1524146079, 1524146079, 1524145939, 
         1524145939, 1524145939, 1524145939, 1524145939, 1524145939, 1524145939, 
         1524145939, 1524145939, 1524145939, 1524145007, 1524145007, 1524145007, 
         1524145007, 1524145007, 1524145007, 1524145007, 1524145007, 1524145007, 
         1524145007, 1524143855, 1524143855, 1524143855, 1524143855, 1524143855, 
         1524143855, 1524143855, 1524143855, 1524143855, 1524143855, 1524143045, 
         1524143045, 1524143045, 1524143045, 1524143045, 1524143045, 1524143045, 
         1524143045, 1524143045, 1524143045, 1524141179, 1524141179, 1524141179, 
         1524141179, 1524141179, 1524141179, 1524141179, 1524141179, 1524141179, 
         1524141179, 1524141025, 1524141025, 1524141025, 1524141025, 1524141025, 
         1524141025, 1524141025, 1524141025, 1524141025, 1524141025), 
  y = c(7, 1, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
        5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
        7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 5, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 6, 4, 
        6, 5, 7, 3, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 
        7, 6, 7, 4, 6, 7, 7, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 
        5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 6, 
        5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 
        6, 6, 4, 7, 7, 4, 7, 3, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 
        4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 
        4, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 4, 5, 
        3, 6, 5, 1, 7, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
        5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 
        6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 
        6, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
        3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 7, 5, 7, 6, 1, 5, 6, 6, 1, 
        7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, 2, 
        2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 
        6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
        6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 4, 
        3, 6, 7, 4, 6, 5, 4, 4, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 
        2, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 
        4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 7, 7, 6, 2, 6, 2, 6, 6, 7, 6, 2, 5, 4, 4, 
        5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 3, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
        5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 6, 6), 
  x1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
         "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
         "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", 
         "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
         "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
         "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
         "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
         "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "E", "E", "E", 
         "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
         "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
         "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
         "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", 
         "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
         "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", 
         "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
         "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
         "A", "A", "A")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -500L), 
  class = "data.frame")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

x1_mean <- data %>% group_by(x1) %>%
  summarize(mean_y = mean(as.numeric(y)))

ggplot(x1_mean, aes(x = x1, y = mean_y, label = round(mean_y, digits = 2))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#336699") +
  geom_label(position = position_nudge(y = 0.1)) +
  xlab("x1") +
  ylab("y") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,7))
```

Comment: Not a bad first question LX8, but we are going to struggle to help you if the question is not fully self contained. What I mean by that is that anyone who tries to run your code in a fresh R session will get only errors, the first being that `%>%` is not found, and neither will any of the functions you use because you have not specified which libraries you are using (include a call to `library(tidyverse)` at the top of your question). You also need to give a sample of data that allows us to run your code. This is what is meant by a [mre].

Comment: A sample (even a made up sample) of data that is the same structure as your own (or similar enough that you could apply any answers to your real data set) is what's really needed. That's probably quite hard to do in this scenario, but writing a good question _is_ hard.

Comment: Thank you for these (gentle) corrections, Allan! I will update soon with the missing information.

Comment: I’ve removed the `experimental-design` tag since your data already exists - you’re asking a retrospective analysis question. Experimental design is all about what experiments you should run prospectively to yield data which maximizes the power of your analysis.

Comment: Understood re: experimental-design. Thanks! I added the missing information @AllanCameron.

Comment: @LX8 thanks - the dput format you have shared is perfect.

Comment: Just made a couple of small edits to your excellent first question to conform to SO guidelines, don't be alarmed. And FYI `dput()` _is_ the best way to share data :)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. One question about your edits: doesn't tidyverse include ggplot2?